# Adding Login activity page Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I added to existing app page as  new activity called LoginActivity page.

1. How can I link to existing app ?
2. How SIGN/REGISTER button works?

Comment: What? Please clarify in more detail

Comment: Actually what you want to do.?

Comment: I had android app  with about and status pages. Now I want to add login page. 

From New Activity menu added ready template of login. Now i don't know how to link with main app. When activity added language xml file and manifest are updated automatic to new activity. Now what I missed to make it work login page

Comment: Codes to long here , system not allows, can I send via mail ? or there is another option to post here ?

Comment: Post here......

Comment: Have too long error to put her the codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136064/discussion-between-haim-rodrik-and-hiren-gondaliya).

Answer (score 5):

From your `Activity` (ex. `MainActivity`) call the `LoginActivity` using  startActivityForResult() method

For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 123);
```

In your `LoginActivity` set the data which you want to return back to `MainActivity`.

For example: In `LoginActivity` if you want to send back data:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now in your `MainActivity` class write following code for the `onActivityResult()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Not logged in
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added new activity password and I don't know how to link to main activity , I tried to use some tips here , without success

Comment: If the application crash is because you have not added it to android manifest . but if you have done , call Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 123);